# How to remove this wire disc cap from a wheel?

Tags: wheels

I'm trying to remove an aftermarket wire hub cap from an old Thunderbird.  I pried off the center cap, revealing an internal mount containing a captive nut:

[image: Wheel cover with center cap removed]

From what I seen in DIY videos, these type of wheel covers usually require a tool for removal, but this one looks different in that it doesn't have a screw holding the assembly onto the center mounting point.  I threaded a bolt into the nut, thinking it would act as a puller and loosen the wheel cover at the center, but doing so did not make any progress, and I don't want to damage the center component.  Also, I tried simply prying the rim of the wheel cover off of the wheel, but it seems to be fastened at the center and it isn't loosening as expected.

What is the correct way of removing this cover?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Isn't that just a wire hubcap on a steel wheel? SHouldn't you just pop the whole thing off? I don't think the wires are actually supporting anything. Would you have a picture of the entire thing?

Comment: ^^^This!  It's not a real wire wheel but just a wire look-alike hubcap.  Pry it off at the edge.

Comment: Have you tried just grabbing the fake spokes and pulling?

Comment: You were all totally right, and I was being overly cautious.  That sucker was on there pretty tight, though!
@Paulster2, you were the first to reply, so if you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct.
Thank you, folks.